# Выпадающий список открываеться в верх а должен в низ

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

можете подсказать как сделать чтобы выпадающий список открывался вниз (так как на 2 сайте с видео), он открывается здесь в верх. Сделано ето через js, сначалала при загрузке страницы смотрю какая высота того блока затем скрываю его и при клике задаю ему ту высоту и он через transition плавно выезжает, но я не могу разобраться чего он выезжает в верх, должен в низ. На 2 сайте (с видео), логика таже самая только там не смотрит высоту а просто задает height: auto и поэтому оно не плавно, я пробовал сделать здесь через auto то оно все равно в верх открывается. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Видео с проблемой: https://youtu.be/fpP1HiVDaZU. Вот код js `

```
    let
        $frequencyRowTestHeight = $(".frequency .frequency-row:nth-child(n+3)").height(),
        counter = 0;

    $(".frequency .frequency-row:nth-child(n+3)").addClass("ready");

    $(".frequency-show").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (counter === 0) {
            $(this).closest(".frequency").find(".frequency-row:nth-child(n+3)").height($frequencyRowTestHeight);
            counter++;
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".frequency").find(".frequency-row:nth-child(n+3)").height(0);
            counter = 0;
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).html("Show less");
        } else {
            $(this).html("Show more");
        }
    });
} else {
    $(".frequency-show").hide();
}`
```

Css:

```
.frequency {
    padding: 20px 45px 10px 70px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.frequency-title {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.frequency-row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.frequency-row:nth-child(n + 3) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s;
}
.frequency-row:nth-child(n + 3).ready {
    position: initial;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.frequency-list {
    width: 24%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.frequency-item {
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.frequency-item:nth-last-of-type(1) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.frequency-row:nth-child(n + 3) .frequency-item:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.frequency-link {
    font: 15px/30px "Museo Sans Cyrl 500", sans-serif;
    color: #39335f;
    line-height: 1px;
}
.frequency-link:hover {
    color: #ea256c;
}
.frequency-link span {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
.frequency-show {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    background: #f5f6f7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    width: 134px;
    height: 32px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font: 13px "Museo Sans Cyrl 500", sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.frequency-show:hover {
    background: #ea256c;
    color: white;
}
.frequency-show::after {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 6px;
    background: url(../img/arr-d.svg) no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.frequency-show:hover::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.frequency-show.active::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="frequency">
      <h2 class="frequency-title">Frequency</h2>
      <div class="frequency-row">
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifoыфыrnia - <span>102.2 FМ</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginывфia - <span>92.1 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvфывфania - <span>101.5 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia - <span>102.2 FМ</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia - <span>102.2 FМ</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia - <span>92.1 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania - <span>101.5 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Coliforфывnia - <span>102.2 FМ</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia - <span>102.2 FМ</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia - <span>92.1 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania - <span>101.5 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornфывia - <span>102.2 FМ</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia - <span>102.2 FМ</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia - <span>92.1 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania - <span>101.5 FM</span></a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia <span>102.2 - FМ</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="frequency-row">
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="frequency-list">
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Virginia 92.1 FM</a></li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Pennsylvania 101.5 FM</a</li>
          <li class="frequency-item"><a class="frequency-link" href="#">Colifornia 102.2 FМ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="frequency-show" href="#">Show more</a>
    </section>
```

Comment: Если удалить все другие блоки вокруг етого на странице, то откриваеться нормально

Comment: Также проблема сощестувует только на Windows, на macOs нету, на Linux не смотрел

Comment: Попробуйте ссылке с классом "frequency-show" убрать действие по умолчанию. e.preventDefault(). Думаю проблема в #

Comment: Попробовал убрать действие по умолчанию и удалить # в всех айтемах, не помогло

Comment: Не в айтемах, а именно в ссылке "Show more". Событие ведь происходит при клике на эту ссылку. Попробуйте сделать "Show more" div-ом, а не ссылкой

Comment: Супер, работает. Спасибо !!

Comment: Закройте тогда вопрос, галочку возле ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте ссылке с классом "frequency-show" убрать действие по умолчанию. e.preventDefault(). Думаю проблема в #